# Apache Nifi: PutParquet creates an invalid file

Tags: apache-nifi

NiFi version - 1.9.1

I'm try read csv and write to parquet.
no errors in NiFi flow, but I can't do it in any way read parquet after NiFi
[image: config PutParquet]
Config CVS reader
[image]

[Avro Scema](https://pastebin.com/mdgLJXg2)

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "namespace": "world_bank",
    "name": "doing_business.updates",
    "fields": [
       filelds
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The guidance going forward here would be to update to a newer version of NiFi and use `ConvertRecord` + `ParquetWriter`.